# Receiving Promise <Pending> instead of value

Tags: node.js, object, promise, return, es6-promise

I have a a object that when I'm printing that it's returning `Promise <Pending>` (I've checked the type of `getRateable` and it is object)

```
getRateable = getRateableEntitiesTx(tx, hashtagList);
```

I can't have access to the value by this :

```
getRateableEntitiesTx(tx, hashtagList).then((res) => {return res})
```

If it's a `Promise` why it's not returning the `res` properly?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: All Promise implementations deliver their value via a `.then()` method. *Some* implementations allow for "synchronous inspection" but it's a non-standard feature. Even in those implementations that provide synchronous inspection, promises are highly likely still to be pending in the event thread in which they were created. Such behaviour is indeterminate because it is not specified anywhere, and in any case should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the value from an async function because the function returns before the value has been received. That's why we have promises. You need to use the value from within the `then()` callback:

```
getRateableEntitiesTx(tx, hashtagList)
.then((rateable) => {
  // use rateable here
  console.log(rateable)
 })
```